# Apache Airflow Dag Import Error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker-compose, airflow

I have 2 tasks in my Dag. The 1st task pulls some data from an API, creates a directory at "/tmp/data" on the worker then writes the data from the API to a file called "test_data.json"
This task executes fine and I can exec onto the worker and access the file.
I added a 2nd task that will read the file in "tmp/data" but the Dag will no longer import because "/tmp/data/test_data.json" doesn't exist.
The file doesn't exist because task 1 hasn't created it yet. I don't understand why this is breaking the Dag, by the time Task 2 needs to read the file, Task 1 will have created it.
I tried separate "write file" and "read file" functions in a blank python document and that ran fine so I'm guessing this is an airflow quirk I'm unaware of.

**Task 1**

```
get_data = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_data',
        method='GET',
        endpoint='endpoint',
        http_conn_id='api',
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer'},
        response_check=lambda response: _handle_response(response),     
        dag=dag
    )
```

**_handle_response**

```
def _handle_response(response):
    print(response.status_code)
    pathlib.Path("/tmp/data").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open("/tmp/data/test_data.json","wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    return True
```

**Task 2**

```
read_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id='read_data',
        python_callable=_data_to_read("/tmp/data/test_data.json"),     
        dag=dag
)
```

**_data_to_read**

```
def _data_to_read(xcom):
    with open(xcom) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second task, your code tries to load the file in dag parsing time instead of reading it in dag runtime for that the Airflow fails to create the dag and add it to the DagBag. You can update it and do something similar to the first task:

```py
read_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id='read_data',
        python_callable=lambda: _data_to_read("/tmp/data/test_data.json"),     
        dag=dag
)

get_data >> read_data
```

After fixing this problem, you need to ensure that the output file of the first task is accessible by the second one. Airflow support multiple type of [executors](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/index.html#executor-types), in the [Local Executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/local.html#local-executor), Airflow creates a process for each task, these tasks are executed locally in the same host (docker container if it's deployed with docker), so all the tasks have an access to the local files, and the result of the other tasks.
But the main goal of Airflow is to run the tasks in a distributed system (Celery, K8S) to ensure fault tolerance and scalability. In this case, the tasks are executed on a group of workers, and most of them cannot access the result of the other tasks which they wrote to the local storage of the worker where they were executed. So if you are using one of these executors, the issue you are facing is normal, because the tasks are executed in two different workers.

So if you want to use a distributed Airflow cluster, you can solve this problem by one of these options:

- creating a shared volume between the workers (docker volume, NFS, K8S volume, ...)
- using an external storage service (S3, GCS, ...) which is recommended to share data between the tasks

Comment: How do your suggestions solve the problem though? If the file doesn't exist on the shared volume or s3, wouldn't OP still have the same issue?